# What's the XAP file equivalent of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xap

Is there such a thing? Maybe there should be, I don't think Microsoft built anything like this but is there a similar format or framework for ASP.NET that let's you deploy an archive -- that is -- your ASP.NET web application, or module that works in the same way?

A xap file is a self-contained archive. I'm particularly interested in the things they're showing with Silverlight 4 and application partitioning. In that you can drop in additional xap files that extend or show up as new things in your app without recompiling the existing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the closest thing would be an assembly.  It is totally possible to compile an ASP.NET website into a single assembly.  Basically you would need to compile your project normally, then [precompile the website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx) and then you could combine all those resulting assemblies into a single assembly using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

Comment: What about *.asxp, *ascx, *.css, *.png all the content and markup that has to be there. If it were just code, it would be one thing, but it's this mix of content and code that needs to be packaged, and then unpackaged or composed into a bigger picture application.

Comment: You can use embedded resources for those.

Comment: If you embed a lot of resources the assembly will grow in size, at some point it's going to cause memory problems in your debug sessions (despite not being executable code). I'm already dealing with a 14MB Telerik assembly, I'm not about to create my own monster.

Comment: Okay, here's the deal, I've revisited this idea recently, and what I had to do was to precompile the app (not precompiling the app is not feasible). Once the app has been precompiled packaing is a matter och zipping all those files togehter. Loading a package is simply loading the assemblies contained in the zip archive, with a small twist, I need to hook the AppDomain ResolveAssembly event and provide the instance/reference for some of the precompiled assemblies, otherwise it cannot find those references since they don't exist anywhere on disk (except contained in a zip archive).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your application in with the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/Downloads/platform.aspx) and get a single deployable installer for your entire site and the common major dependencies/frameworks, this is the closet equivalent that I'm aware of.  Some popular projects have deployments available in this fashion, [see here for a list](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/).

[Hanselman did a post on how to package your app this way](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MicrosoftWebPlatformWebApplicationGalleryWebPlatformInstallerAndDasBlog.aspx) that might be a good starting point to get a feel for the process.

Comment: This is not a question about deployment, in that I wanna deploy and entire application. It's about application partitioning. I wanna deploy an application in small pieces.

Comment: @John - Not sure that's possible as they're all compiled against one another.  Can you give an example of how you'd split an application, which pieces?

Comment: There's a lot of fuzz about this on Silverlight TV (search Channel 9) through MEF a surface is exposed and a component or control pops in there when discovered as belonging to this exported surface. Basically any part of the application could sit in one of those self contained xap files as long as their mutual dependencies exists shared somewhere else. It's all very magical and very interesting.